# How to move a dense mesh irregular object above other object surface in a especific direction?

Tags: animation, mesh, physics, properties, collision

Hello I m new in Blender and I ve trying to solve the next problem for a long time but I couldn t find an appropite solution. So I m writing to you and maybe you can help me. My problem is the following' I animate one object (A) with some partticular movement then with (control L-- animation data) linked this movement settings to other object (B) so all the group have the same behaviour. Now put on the pathway of the object B linked, another object (C) and now I want the object B  when contact with object C slide obove object C surface contacting with it with out overlaping meshes and then, when contact finish,]object B follow come back its original pathway...I try setting rigid body and collision in physical properties but meshes of object B and C continues overlapping.
[image]

Comment: Overcomplicated. What is object A for then?

Comment: Object A is a uv sphere where I set a movenmet...then object C is a superior part of a Suzane head and  B inferior part of Suzane head...I want when  play animaction inferior part of Susane head B move contacting according C surface superior part of Suzane head follow the movement dirección setting in A and Linked in B